# Laravel get data based on date

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to get data from DB based on the input date,
If there is data with a previous date then it will give me output.

But say the current date is 2024-02-22 and DB doesn't have data for 2024-02-21 or 20, but has data for 19, this means we need to find data which is close to the current date, then how can I get it? my current code gets only the previous date, but need to find data which is close to current date,

```
foreach ($file as $row) {

   $current_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-M-Y', str_replace(' ', '', $row[2]))->format('Y-m-d');

   $carbonDate = Carbon::parse($current_date);
   $previous_date = $carbonDate->subDay()->format('Y-m-d');

   //Now find data of the previous day with symbol and date.
   $pd = EodBhavData::where('symbol', $row[0])->where('date', $previous_date)->first();

\\ Compare code and calculations...

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
where('date', $previous_date)
```

to

```
where('date', '<=', $previous_date)
```

or

```
whereDate('date', '<=', $previous_date)
```

Your current condition is only pointing to exact `$previous_date` that is why only "2024-02-21" is retrieved.

Personally, I would use `whereDate`

Comment: Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

Comment: Thank you, that means even if i don't calculate previous date and simply use ```<``` it should get me previous data.

Comment: yeah you can just use `<` then the right side is carbon today